# How to add traffic information to routing?

Tags: here-api

I am testing out isochrones API https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-isoline.html from HERE Routing and I can't make the traffic information alter the results in any way.

When I request isochrones the traffic switch does not change the result at all. See the following sample requests. Both pairs give the exact same results even though the traffic setting is enabled/disabled.

**New York - Manhattan**

Traffic enabled

```
https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!40.7599503,73.9805014&range=1200&departure=2019-11-26T17:30:00%2B01:00
```

Traffic disabled

```
https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!40.7599503,73.9805014&range=1200&departure=2019-11-26T17:30:00%2B01:00
```

**Prague - also city center**

Traffic enabled

```
https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!50.0756353,14.4215244&range=1200&departure=2019-12-04T17:30:00%2B01:00
```

Traffic disabled

```
https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rangetype=time&start=geo!50.0756353,14.4215244&range=1200&departure=2019-12-04T17:30:00%2B01:00
```

I get the same behaviour even for the simple route API (but I am mainly interested in isochrones):

**New York - route**

Traffic enabled

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&rangetype=time&waypoint0=geo!40.7599503,73.9805014&waypoint1=geo!40.8389097,73.8310378&range=1200&departure=2019-11-26T17:30:00%2B01:00
```

Traffic disabled

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&rangetype=time&waypoint0=geo!40.7599503,73.9805014&waypoint1=geo!40.8389097,73.8310378&range=1200&departure=2019-11-26T17:30:00%2B01:00
```

The date does not change the fact the traffic is not considered (I have tried future, present and past dates and times).

Currently I am on trial account.

As HERE has no IT or API support available and they only redirect to stackoverflow.com I am asking here.

Is the traffic informtion available for routes and isochrones as written in above-mentioned documentation? Or is the problem in the trial nature of my account?

Or what else can be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The examples you gave for the routing API is only `9.4km` distance with little or no traffic. That is why you do not see any difference in the time results. If you use longer distances on busy roads, you will see that enabling/disabling traffic makes a difference in the results. For example try a start waypoint of `52.379189,4.899431` (Amsterdam) to `51.44083,5.47778` (Eindhoven) in the Netherlands and you will see a difference with and without traffic information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am interested in planning routes inside cities. In my personal experience traffic situation inside a city can change the duration of trips (even with length of about 9km) very much. So inside cities, there really is not that much of a difference according to HERE Maps?

Comment: It all depends on the traffic history of the location. If there is a huge traffic in a particular city within certain periods of time, then this traffic data will be taken into consideration during your route planning by the HERE APIs.